# Spring Boot JPA : How to delete child entity of a Many to One relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm turning totaly crazy with a "simple" case to implement

=> i want to remove a child entity nested to a parent entity via a relation Many to One.

Quite simple simple isn't it ? Unfortunatly not for me :-(

Below all my code, and my attempts

1st => the parent entity :

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = "books")
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Book> books;

    public Category(String name, Book... books) {
        this.name = name;
        this.books = Stream.of(books).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        this.books.forEach(x -> x.setCategory(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Category)) return false;
        Category category = (Category) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, category.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }

}
```

And then the child entity :

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = "category")
@Entity
public class Book{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private @NonNull String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Category category;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Book)) return false;
        Book book = (Book) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, book.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }

}
```

The 2 Repo

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE Book b WHERE b.category.id = ?1")
    void deleteByCategoryId(int categoryId);

    List<Book> findByCategoryId(int categoryId);
}

public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {
}
```

And the extract of the Pom.xml file i'm using :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

Suprisingly, everything works well when i try to delete the parent entity

```
int categoryId2 = categoryRepository.saveAndFlush(new Category("B", new Book("B1"), new Book("B2"))).getId();
Category category2 = categoryRepository.findById(categoryId2).get();
categoryRepository.delete(category2);
// Category and the 2 nested books have been removed from the DB
```

First attempt to remove only one book and the outcome:

```
int categoryId = categoryRepository.saveAndFlush(new Category("A", new Book("A1"), new Book("A2"))).getId();
//Category and nested 2 books are perfectly persisted in DB

Category category = categoryRepository.findById(categoryId).get();
Book book = category.getBooks().iterator().next();
int bookId = book.getId();
category.getBooks().remove(book);
//to remove the link in the parent entity
book.setCategory(null);
//to remove the link in the child entity
categoryRepository.flush();
// to persist in the DB 
// At this point, with the help of the orphanRemoval (true) property, i was expecting than the book would have been removed from the DB
// But nothing happened :-(
```

Second try with "crazy workaround"

```
int categoryId = categoryRepository.saveAndFlush(new Category("A", new Book("A1"), new Book("A2"))).getId();

Category category = categoryRepository.findById(categoryId).get();
Book book = category.getBooks().iterator().next();
int bookId = book.getId();
category.getBooks().remove(book);
book.setCategory(null);
categoryRepository.flush();
//Same result as the first attempt, nothing happened in the DB

bookRepository.delete(book);
// with this delete call => the link was removed in the DB, book.category_id=null

bookRepository.delete(book);
// with this 2nd delete call => great result => the book entity was removed in the db
```

Is anyone can help me by giving me the good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,  fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Book> books;
```

Notice that

cascade = **CascadeType.PERSIST**

Hope it would help. 
[Hibernate Tips: How to delete child entities from a many-to-one association](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-delete-child-entities/)